# AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'IGNORECASE' ...only in pyenv build

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

On my Mac OSX pyenv python 3.7.3, a simple base converter fails with

```
  File "/Users/geo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 88, in Template
    flags = _re.IGNORECASE
```

the same code works with brew 3.7.3

reinstalled pyenv 3.7.3, and compared 3.7.3/lib/python3.7/string.py files (they are the same), here is the program

```
import sys
import string

digs = string.digits + string.ascii_letters

def d2b(x, b):
    if x < 0:
        sign = -1
    elif x == 0:
        return digs[0]
    else:
        sign = 1
    x *= sign
    digits = []
    while x:
        digits.append(digs[int(x % b)])
        x = int(x / b)
    if sign < 0:
        digits.append('-')
    digits.reverse()
    return ''.join(digits)

print(d2b(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2])))
```

Here is a success, and failed invocation...

```
 /usr/local/bin/python3 lang/py/d2b.py 17 16
11
 /Users/geo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python3.7 lang/py/d2b.py 17 16
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lang/py/d2b.py", line 3, in <module>
    import string
  File "/Users/geo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 78, in <module>
    class Template(metaclass=_TemplateMetaclass):
  File "/Users/geo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/string.py", line 88, in Template
    flags = _re.IGNORECASE
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'IGNORECASE'
```

Thanks for any tips on where to look next!

Comment: Try running `import re` followed by `print(re)`. Are you by any chance name shadowing the built in module with an `re.py` of your own?

Comment: Thanks for the debug tip! I've rebuilt my 3.7.3 
`>>> import sys ; import string ; import re ; print(re)`
`<module 're' from '/Users/geo/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/re.py'>`
no kind of `re.py` that I can find....

Comment: @ShadowRanger more details are here... https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1367

Answer (score 0):

Did you place a `re.py` in the working directory? && Don’t.